# Обработка данных, размещённых в excel-файле

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, dataframe

Решаю следующую задачу:

В наличии два листа книги Excel,

- `лист 1` содержит 726 записей, каждая из которых представляет пару значений переменных a и b, расположенных в колонках `A` и `B` соответственно (a в `A`, b в `B`), тип связей между значениями колонок `A` и `B` "один к одному" и "один ко многим" (т.е., одному значению из колонки `A` может соответствовать как одно значение из колонки `B`, так и более одного).
- `лист 2` содержит 4700 записей, каждая запись представляет из себя тоже, что и запись на листе A: значения переменных a и b в колонках `A` и `B` соответственно.

Необходимо, на `лист 3`, в колонках `A` и `B`, разместить все записи из `лист 1`  и все записи из `лист 2`. Удалить все дубликаты пар значений, затем, упорядочить все записи следующим образом:

Сначала разместить записи, у которых тип связи между значениями переменных a и b (в колонках `A` и `B`) "один к одному", потом разместить записи, у которых тип связи между значениями переменных a и b (в колонках `A` и `B`) "один ко многим", на первой позиции разместить колонку `C`, содержащей индекс.

В качестве примера привожу прототипы входных и выходных данных:

лист 1:
колонка `A`: `1 2 3 4 1 3 4 2 1`
колонка `B`: `5 6 7 8 5 7 8 6 6`

лист 2:
колонка `A`: `6 7 8 9 10 6 7 12 12 14 11`
колонка `B`: `1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 12`

лист 3:
колонка `C`: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14`
колонка `A`: `2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 14 11 1 1 12 12`
колонка `B`:  `6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 5 12 5 6 3 4`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли решить с помощью pandas и, если да, то каким образом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Геннадий, добрый день.
Вы конечно очень усложнили задачу, пришлось перечитать несколько раз.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#читаем Excel и сливаем два датафрейма
filename = 'C:\\temp\\Gena.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=0,header=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=1,header=0)
frames = [df1, df2]
df3 = pd.concat(frames)

#переиндексируем датафрейм
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True)

#убираем дубликаты    
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()

#считаем дубликаты
df3['count'] = df3.groupby('A')['A'].transform('count')
#сортируем датафрейм согласно постановке и реиндексируем
df3 = df3.sort_values(['count', 'A']).reset_index(drop=True)
#проверяем что все правильно
print(df3)

#пишем новым листом в книгу
book = load_workbook(filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df3.to_excel(writer, "Лист3")
writer.save()
```

Comment: Юрий, добрый день. Благодарю за помощь. Вникаю.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно добавить следующее: в выходных данных, на листе 3, между колонками C и A необходимо разместить колонку Key, прототип  выходных значений должен быть следующий: Key: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 11 12 12. Т.е., у повторяющихся значений колонки A (групп значений), значения колонки Key должны быть одинаковыми. Заранее спасибо.